# Copying a range from new workbook into active workbook without using clipboard

Tags: vba

I have an active open workbook with a macro running. I need to open another (new) workbook, and copy a range of cell from first worksheet of the 'new' file and append those rows to the bottom of a worksheet in my current workbook. I would like to avoid using copy/paste using the clipboard. Here is my code:

```
Sub getnewrows()

Dim lngLast As Integer, newLast As Integer
Dim NewRows As Workbook
Dim MyWkbk As Workbook
Dim rSrc As Range
Dim rDst As Range

Set MyWkbk = ActiveWorkbook
Sheets(3).Select
lngLast = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set NewRows = Application.Workbooks.Open("pathtomyfile.xls")
newLast = NewRows.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rSrc = NewRows.Sheets(1).Range("A5:L" & newLast)
Set rDst = MyWkbk.Sheets(3).Range("A" & lngLast + 1)

rDst = rSrc.Value

NewRows.Close

Set MyWkbk = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub
```

Starting with my (current) workbook already open, and the 'new' one closed, when I run the macro, it only copies over one cell.

Comment: using copy and destination is not good enough ?

Comment: `Set rDst = MyWkbk.Sheets(3).Range("A" & lngLast + 1)` or `Set rDst = MyWkbk.Sheets(3).Cells(lngLast + 1, "A")`  BTW `lngLast` has not been assigned a value, so will default to zero

Comment: Also, you could consider using SQL with ADO if you wanted to filter the data prior to bringing it over to the main doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cells` doesn't take that type of parameter.

```
Set rDst = MyWkbk.Sheets(3).Ran‌​ge("A" & lngLast + 1)
```

or

```
Set rDst = MyWkbk.Sheets(3).Cel‌​ls(lngLast + 1, "A")
```

BTW lngLast has not been assigned a value, so will default to zero

Comment: I tried that. It copies over just one cell value. The one from NewRows.Sheet(1).cells("A5") into Mywkbk.Sheets(3).Cells(lngLast+1,"A").  How can I get the full row and all rows in NewRows workbook that are after row 5 ? I have updated code above.

Comment: I got it! I had to update set Rdst to      Set rDst = MyWkbk.Sheets(3).Range("A" & lngLast + 1 & ":L" & lngLast + 1 + newLast - 5)

Comment: I tried to mark this question answered but when I click the checkmark I keep getting "An error has occurred. Please re-try your request"